# filling NA values in data frame with values common based on unique id

Tags: r

I have a large data frame and part of it look like this:

```
   id carbon nitrogen sulfer
1   1     NA       NA     NA
2   1     NA       NA     NA
3   1      5        6     78
4   2     NA       NA     NA
5   2     NA       NA     NA
6   2      8        8     67
7   3     NA       NA     NA
8   3     NA       NA     NA
9   3     NA       NA     NA
10  3      7        9     55
```

Is there a way I can filled the `NA` values in columns (example carbon), with one value given common to id. For example if we take `id == 1` then for column carbon has value of 5 and need to replace `NA` with 5. 
I have nearly 200 columns to filled like this.

Any help to automate this is much appreciated.

Comment: Also, is it a coincidence that on each row you either have `NA` everywhere or nowhere?

Comment: OK. What I'm trying to fill the data frame for missing values. So each is a location in landscape (unique id). So values for 3 columns are same same for that unique id

Comment: The question is clear. For each id there is a unique non-NA value per column. Or could be more, but all values the same. And the position should be uncaring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't really clarified the issues pointed out by @flodel in his comments. Anyway, *given* the pattern in your example data, i.e. all values of carbon nitrogen sulfer are missing, except the *last within each id*, then you can try this:

```
library(zoo)
na.locf(df, na.rm = FALSE, fromLast = TRUE)

#    id carbon nitrogen sulfer
# 1   1      5        6     78
# 2   1      5        6     78
# 3   1      5        6     78
# 4   2      8        8     67
# 5   2      8        8     67
# 6   2      8        8     67
# 7   3      7        9     55
# 8   3      7        9     55
# 9   3      7        9     55
# 10  3      7        9     55
```

Comment: It works. Thanks @Henrik. What about if the level of id sub levels different from each other. Example id==1 consists of 3 sub levels while id==2 consists of 2 sub levels

Comment: And if the position is not always the last, but another one?

Comment: @iago Then you need to fill _by group_, forwards and backwards. See e.g. [Filling in missing (blanks) in a data table, per category - backwards and forwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607465/filling-in-missing-blanks-in-a-data-table-per-category-backwards-and-forwar), [Replace NA with previous or next value, by group, using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040834/replace-na-with-previous-or-next-value-by-group-using-dplyr)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I hope it what you need. If not update and I update the result. By the way this was asked a few times already.

```
myFunc <- function(value) {
  if (value[1] == 1) {
    value[2] = 5;
    value[3] = 5;
    value[4] = 5 
  }
  # here you put you're if's
}

apply(data, 1, myFunc)
```