# Replacing NAs with non-NA values by ID

Tags: r

In `df` I would like to replace the NA values with the non-NA value for each id

```
id<-c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2)
price<-c(NA,20,NA,NA,NA,NA,5)
df<-data.frame(id,price)

 id    price
  1       NA
  1       20
  1       NA
  1       NA
  2       NA
  2       NA
  2        5
```

The output should ideally look like:

```
id      price
  1       20
  1       20
  1       20
  1       20
  2        5
  2        5
  2        5
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `df$price <- ave(df$price, df$id, FUN=function(x) { x[is.na(x)] <- mean(x, na.rm=TRUE); x} )`

Comment: `tidyr::fill` in both the directions. `df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(price, .direction = "up") %>%
  fill(price)`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040834/replace-na-with-previous-or-next-value-by-group-using-dplyr

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace NA with previous or next value, by group, using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040834/replace-na-with-previous-or-next-value-by-group-using-dplyr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, price := price[!is.na(price)], id]
df

#    id price
# 1:  1    20
# 2:  1    20
# 3:  1    20
# 4:  1    20
# 5:  2     5
# 6:  2     5
# 7:  2     5
```