# How to apply value in first row to all subsequent rows by participant using the tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

Just say we run a study where participants are measured on some outcome variable four times each. At the start of testing they provide their age and sex. Here is some toy data to illustrate.

```
set.seed(1)
sex <- NA
age <- NA
df <- data.frame(id = factor(rep(1:4,each=4)),
                 time = rep(1:4,times=4),
                 sex = as.vector(sapply(0:3, function(i) sex[i*4 + 1:4] <- c(sample(c("m", "f"), 1, replace = T), rep(NA,3)))),
                 age = as.vector(sapply(0:3, function(i) age[i*4 + 1:4] <- c(sample(18:75, 1, replace = T), rep(NA,3)))),
                 outcome = round(rnorm(16),2),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Here is what the data looks like

```
df

# output
# id time  sex age outcome
#  1    1    m  29    0.33
#  1    2 <NA>  NA   -0.82
#  1    3 <NA>  NA    0.49
#  1    4 <NA>  NA    0.74
#  2    1    m  70    0.58
#  2    2 <NA>  NA   -0.31
#  2    3 <NA>  NA    1.51
#  2    4 <NA>  NA    0.39
#  3    1    f  72   -0.62
#  3    2 <NA>  NA   -2.21
#  3    3 <NA>  NA    1.12
#  3    4 <NA>  NA   -0.04
#  4    1    f  56   -0.02
#  4    2 <NA>  NA    0.94
#  4    3 <NA>  NA    0.82
#  4    4 <NA>  NA    0.59
```

Now what I want to do is to use the `tidyverse` to apply the values for the demographic variables, at present only on the first row of each participant's data, to all the rows.

At present all I could come up with was

```
df %>% group_by(id) %>% # group by id
       distinct(sex) %>% # shrink to unique values for each id
       dplyr::filter(!is.na(sex)) %>% # remove the NAs
       left_join(df, by = "id")
```

Which yields the output

```
# A tibble: 16 x 6
# Groups:   id [4]
#    sex.x id     time sex.y   age outcome
#    <chr> <fct> <int> <chr> <int>   <dbl>
#  1 m     1         1 m        29   0.33 
#  2 m     1         2 NA       NA  -0.82 
#  3 m     1         3 NA       NA   0.49 
#  4 m     1         4 NA       NA   0.74 
#  5 m     2         1 m        70   0.580
#  6 m     2         2 NA       NA  -0.31 
#  7 m     2         3 NA       NA   1.51 
#  8 m     2         4 NA       NA   0.39 
#  9 f     3         1 f        72  -0.62 
# 10 f     3         2 NA       NA  -2.21 
# 11 f     3         3 NA       NA   1.12 
# 12 f     3         4 NA       NA  -0.04 
# 13 f     4         1 f        56  -0.02 
# 14 f     4         2 NA       NA   0.94 
# 15 f     4         3 NA       NA   0.82 
# 16 f     4         4 NA       NA   0.59
```

Now I would consider this partially successful because the first row in each participant's `sex.x` column has now been applied to all their other rows, but I really don't like that there are now *two* sex columns.

Now I could easily add some more functions to the chain that remove the superfluous `sex.y` column and rename the `sex.x` column to its original form, but this seems a bit clunky.

**Can anyone suggest how to do this better?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing NAs with latest non-NA value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735647/replacing-nas-with-latest-non-na-value).  This is a better dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40040834/replace-na-with-previous-or-next-value-by-group-using-dplyr.

Comment: Yes the second one answers the same question the same way.

Comment: Maybe your previous step(s) needs a make-over. How is the data generated? If your data are separated into two data frames (one for baseline data and one for follow-up data), merging them together will give you your desired output, and no need to `fill` anything.

Comment: Sadly @Edward they were all part of the same extract from a redcap database. I could have extracted the datasets separately and done it that way no question. This question was more for my edification than anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `fill` the `sex` value for each `id` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id) %>% tidyr::fill(sex)

#   id     time sex     age outcome
#   <fct> <int> <chr> <int>   <dbl>
# 1 1         1 m        51  -1.54 
# 2 1         2 m        NA  -0.93 
# 3 1         3 m        NA  -0.290
# 4 1         4 m        NA  -0.01 
# 5 2         1 f        40   2.4  
# 6 2         2 f        NA   0.76 
# 7 2         3 f        NA  -0.8  
# 8 2         4 f        NA  -1.15 
# 9 3         1 m        60  -0.290
#10 3         2 m        NA  -0.3  
#11 3         3 m        NA  -0.41 
#12 3         4 m        NA   0.25 
#13 4         1 m        31  -0.89 
#14 4         2 m        NA   0.44 
#15 4         3 m        NA  -1.24 
#16 4         4 m        NA  -0.22
```

You could also `fill` `age` value.(`df %>% group_by(id) %>% tidyr::fill(sex, age)`).

PS - I get different numbers from the same seed value though.

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah, so simple. I knew there had to be a verb out there for this problem.